# Right rotation of a 16-bit non-negative number?

Tags: c, rotation, bitwise-operators, unsigned

I'm working on a method in which I need to perform a right rotation. For instance, I have the binary number 0101110111000111, and after the method is performed, the result should be 1010111011100011. A 16-bit non-negative number is passed as the parameter, and this parameter value will have all the bits moved to the right by 1 bit position and with the low-order bit moved to the high-order position (like the example above).

Here is the code I have written. I converted 0101110111000111 to the decimal value of 24007.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int rotateRight(unsigned int x);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  unsigned int n = 24007; 
  printf("%d\n", rotateRight(n, d)); 
  return 0; 
} 

/*Function to right rotate n by d bits*/
unsigned int rotateRight(unsigned int x) {
  return (x >> 1) | (x << (16-1));
}
```

My expected result should be the value of 44771, because that is the decimal equivalent to 1010111011100011. However, when I run this program, I get 786673379. Could someone explain why this is happening, and how I could improve my rotation function so I can get the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

`(x << (16-1)` shifts the entire 16-bit quantity 15 places to the left and prepends it to the `x >> 1`. Since `int` can hold a 32-bit value and therefore doesn't truncate your calculation, you get a 31-bit value as a result.

i.e.

```
x = 0101 1101 1100 0111
x >> 1 = 0010 1110 1110 0011
x << (16 -1) = 0010 1110 1110 0011 1000 0000 0000 0000

=> (x >> 1) | (x << (16-1))
    = 0101110111000111010111011100011 (binary)
    = 786673379 (decimal)
```

A solution would be:

```
unsigned int rotateRight(unsigned int x) {
  return ((x >> 1) | (x << (16-1))) & 0xffff;
}
```

i.e. do the calculation you're already doing, but keep only the lowest 16 bits.

Alternatively you could use a type like `uint16_t` to ensure that larger numbers are automatically truncated, subject to your feelings about implicit type conversions and explicit type conversion syntax.

Comment: Thank you, this is great, and makes total sense. I forgot that ints can hold 32 bits and therefore my solution wasn't being truncated. I tried your way and it works!